ASP.NET Core: how/where to call the SignOutAsync to logout from a custom authentication?
In an ASP.NET Core (razor pages) project I've implemented a custom authentication with a cookie that carries the custom claims, and I've specified login and logout pages/paths via the CookieAuthenticationOptions parameter and everything works decently.
    // Lightweight authentication
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(LightweightAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(LightweightAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.Cookie.Name = LightweightAuthDefaults.CookiePrefix;
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                        options.LoginPath = LightweightAuthDefaults.LoginPath;
                        options.LogoutPath = LightweightAuthDefaults.LogoutPath;
                        options.AccessDeniedPath = LightweightAuthDefaults.AccessDeniedPath;
                        options.ReturnUrlParameter = LightweightAuthDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                    });

The two things I don't like of my implementation are that

I'm calling the SignOutAsync in the OnGet of the logout page thus
during the logout razor page rendering the user is really still
authenticated (I suppose that the cookie will be dropped when the logout page
response is returned to the user) so if the page were to display the authenticated user name it would still find the user as logged in
Since the user during logout page rendering is
still authenticated and the SignOutAsync call does not return any
success/failure (it is probably not feasible to reliably say anything that depends on dropping a browser cookie) I cannot be sure that when the user
received the logout page response the logout is indeed achieved and
thus displaying any message such as "you have been logged out" would be meaningless

I was thinking of changing my implementation as follows: set as logout path a mvc controller that calls the SignOutAsync and then redirects the user (the 301 response sent back to the browser would also carry the request to drop the auth cookie) to the logout page that at this point would be able to verify if the user is indeed logged out and eventually take some other action. Would this be a better approach? Is there any pattern for reliably achieving a logout?

I don’t understand the issue. Does your site forget who the user is upon logout, or not?

Based on my tests it does, if you read my post I wrote it. Truth is that while the logout page is being rendered the user is still logged in. I was wondering is there is a better approach or even a standard approach to logging out users that leads to having the logout page executed when the user has already been logged out.

"SignOutAsync call does not return any success/failure" , actually after logout you could challenge the cookie scheme again manually to redirect to unauthorized page.
